# mysqli bind_result()/ only returning nul

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am having a fair bit of trouble with the mysqli's `bind_result()` and `fetch()` functions.

I have tried a few things including echoing the result of:

```
$sql->prepare()
$sql->bind_param()
$sql->execute()
$sql->bind_result()
```

and they were all returning true the only function that is returning `false` is `$sql->fetch()`

the mysqli connection info is as follows:

```
<?php
 $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','false','data','battlestar');  

 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  $siteOffline = 1;
  $smarty->assign("Fail", "Site is offline");
 }
?>
```

and the mysqli prepared statment that I am having trouble with is here:

```
$UID = "";
$userLevel = "";

if(isset($_POST['hidden'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = crypt($_POST['password']);

if($username != "" || $password != ""){
if($sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT UID, userLevel FROM users WHERE username=? AND   password=?")){

$sql->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
$result = $sql->execute();

$res = $sql->bind_result($UID, $userLevel);

$sql->fetch();

var_dump($sql->error_list);

echo $UID . ' ' . $userLevel;
var_dump($sql);
if($result == NULL){
$smarty->assign("error", "Username or password invalid, please try again");
}
else{
$smarty->assign("confirmation", "Logged in Sucessfully");

$_SESSION['UID'] = $UID;
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = 1;
$_SESSION['userLevel'] = $userLevel;
}
}
}
else{
$smarty->assign("error", "You must enter a username and password");
}
}

$smarty->assign("content", $smarty->fetch("login.tpl"));
require_once("footer.php");
?>
```

I am using php 5.4 and mysql 5.5

so my problem is that the fields that I select in the query and `bind_result()` only return NULL and I have been through the documentation  of [bind_result()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#92505) over and over yet I can't seem to find a solution.

sorry if this is fairly obvious or has already been asked I did look at like 5 other posts but none of them were completely relational.

if any more data is needed please tell me what you need.

Comment: For all the goodness sake, don't use mysqli. It's way harder than average PHP user can bear with. Use [PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) instead.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I partly agree with you. PDO has a steeper learning curve than MySQLi as its syntax is totally different than traditional deprecated `mysql_*` libraries. MySQLi is fine if you work with a lightweight DB wrapper, like [PHP DB Manager](https://github.com/shivanraptor/PHP-DB-Manager).

Comment: @ShivanRaptor like most wrappers, this one makes things even worse.

Comment: Not quite agree with you. Microsoft and FedEx are using the same wrapper in their system.

Comment: Well, I pity them then. *If* they really using this very wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading *whole* your question through, the answer is clear - your query returned no results.
That's the very and the only reason for your variables to contain null.

Comment: thank you for your fast response.   so would you suggest that I re-look at my queries?

Comment: Better re-look at your data, either one stored in database and one you're typing in form. It have to match.

Answer (score -1):

If `$sql->fetch()` returns `false`, it means that error(s) occurred. If it returns `null`, it means "no more rows". Review the error by issuing `var_dump($sql->error);`.

Also, if you want to retrieve the data from `fetch()`, you should:

```
$sql->bind_result($UID, $userLevel);
while($sql->fetch()) {
  printf ("%d (%s)\n", $UID, $userLevel);
}
```

Reference: [mysqli_stmt::fetch on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

Comment: "working code" has noting to do with " it means that error(s) occurred. " statement

Comment: errors occurred is from php.net documentation. Read carefully @YourCommonSense (especially in Returned Values section).thanks!

Comment: Ok, I re-read it. there is nothing related to the question asked.